# What design choice use in this scenario to avoid violating the LSP?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm refactoring a few applications (scrapers) I've created into one single application. There are a few scrapers, like `TwitterScraper`, `FacebookScraper`, etc. The names are just for explaining better the problem.

Let's suppose I want to retrieve people using those scrapers. We could search using different ways in each scraper. For example, in Facebook we could search by Name, Age, etc.... or simply get all the users in some specific group, which means we have two ways of searching there. The same can happen to Twitter, and others...

I thought about having the following design:

```
public interface IScraper {
    IEnumerable<User> Search(IParameter parameters);
}
```

and then have:

```
public class FacebookGroupsScraper : IScraper {
    public IEnumerable<User> Search(IParameter parameters) {
        //... search here using the group url, etc.
    }
}

public class FacebookOtherScraper : IScraper {
    public IEnumerable<User> Search(IParameter parameters) {
        //... search here using the name, age, country, or whatever...
    }
}
```

but I'm definitely violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), since I would have to do something like this in each method:

```
public class FacebookOtherScraper : IScraper {
    public IEnumerable<User> Search(IParameter parameters) {
        var p = parameters as FacebookOtherParameter;

        //We can only work here with the expected parameters 
        //(FacebookOtherParameter class in this case)
    }
}
```

What would be a good way to design it?

Comment: If you're going to vote to close this question, I'm not looking for **the best** way of avoiding this. I just want to know a good alternative...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the difference between implementations are the types of parameters they take.

Therefore, in order to adhere to the LSP I think it is better to change your interface to either have separate methods or to have separate interfaces, each with a different method that take different types of parameters:

```
//... search here using the group url, etc.
public interface GroupScrapper{
     IEnumerable<User> SearchByGroup(IGroupParameter parameters...);

}
 //... search here using the name, age, country, or whatever...
public interface UserInfoScrapper{
     IEnumerable<User> SearchByInfo(IInfoParameter parameters...);

}
```

or as a single interface:

```
public interface IScraper {
    IEnumerable<User> SearchByGroup(IGroupParameter parameters...);

    IEnumerable<User> SearchByInfo(IInfoParameter parameters...);
}
```

This way every implementation will meet the contract of one of the methods.

The problem with this approach is you would have to have a pretty static parameter set that is fully known ahead of time.  If you have to keep adding new types of parameters then the number of methods and/or interfaces will explode.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do generic for this case. (please note the code below may not compile)

```
public interface IScraper<T> where T : IParameter
{
    IEnumerable<User> Search(T parameters);
}

public class FacebookParameter : IParameter{
    public string GroupUrl{ get; set; }
}

public class FacebookGroupsScraper : IScraper<FacebookParameter> {
    public IEnumerable<User> Search(FacebookParameter parameters) {
        //... search here using the group url, etc.
    }
}
```

However I forgot about how to use it at consumer level though.